# How this CREATE statement is parsed by sqlplus?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I saw some CREATE statements I never thought could be parsed by SQLPLUS:

```
plus@PDB1> #create 
2  or 
3  replace procedure p as 
4  begin 
5  null; 
6  end; 
7  / 

Procedure created. 

plus@PDB1> #create 
2  table t3(x int); 

Table created.
```

So how the pound signs (#) were parsed here ? I cannot find any documentation for this. If there is a documentation to it, point me there.

Comment: Which DB/version you are connecting to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [`SQLPREFIX` character](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch12040.htm#i2679105). The manual describes it:

> While you are entering a SQL command or PL/SQL block, you can enter a SQL*Plus command on a separate line, prefixed by the SQL*Plus prefix character. SQL*Plus will execute the command immediately without affecting the SQL command or PL/SQL block that you are entering.

An example use case of running a SQL*Plus® command inside a SQL command:

```
SQL> SELECT *
# show release
release 1102000200
FROM dual;

D
-
X
```

While you would usually use this to run something immediately inside a larger command, since you can use it anywhere, you can actually use it on its own too.

```
SQL> # SELECT * FROM dual;

D
-
X
```